# Error twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable Running scrapy spider from python Script using get_project_settings()

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scrapy spider from script . I follow scrapy documentation and implemented in this way .
**my_script.py**

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('followall', domain='scrapinghub.com')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished 
process.stop()
```

And i have manipulate followall spider in this way for testing purpose. 
**followall.py**

```
import re
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse

import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, HtmlResponse
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from testspiders.items import Page


class FollowAllSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'followall'

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(FollowAllSpider, self).__init__(**kw)
        url = kw.get('url') or kw.get('domain') or 'http://scrapinghub.com/'
        if not url.startswith('http://') and not url.startswith('https://'):
            url = 'http://%s/' % url
        self.url = url
        self.allowed_domains = [re.sub(r'^www\.', '', urlparse(url).hostname)]
        self.link_extractor = LinkExtractor()
        self.cookies_seen = set()

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        print ('\n\n===============This is followall ==================\n\n')
```

when I am running **my_script.py** script , it try to run **followall** spider two times and end with following exception

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/Denave_Python_Projects/testspiders-master/testspiders/fisttest.py
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.utils.log] **INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: testspiders)**
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'testspiders', 'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 1000, 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT': 3600, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'testspiders.spiders', 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['testspiders.spiders']}
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['testspiders.middleware.RandomUserAgent',
 'testspiders.middleware.ErrorMonkeyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-04-24 18:51:18 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://scrapinghub.com/> from <GET http://scrapinghub.com/>
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://scrapinghub.com/> (referer: None)
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)


2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
**===============This is followall ==================**
{'downloader/request_bytes': 624,


 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 13326,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 24, 13, 21, 19, 730915),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 24, 13, 21, 18, 498736)}
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.core.engine] **INFO: Spider closed (finished)**
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.utils.log] **INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: testspiders)**
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'testspiders', 'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 1000, 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT': 3600, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'testspiders.spiders', 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['testspiders.spiders']}
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['testspiders.middleware.RandomUserAgent',
 'testspiders.middleware.ErrorMonkeyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-04-24 18:51:19 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/Denave_Python_Projects/testspiders-master/testspiders/fisttest.py", line 6, in <module>
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 291, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1242, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1222, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 730, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Questions:**

**1. Any solution for this Error twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable in this case**

**2. Any other way to run already written spider from python Script**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `process.stop()` there, it's used with `CrawlerRunner` and you are using `CrawlerProcess`. The difference is that the former supposes you application already has a reactor loop to attach to, and the latter sets up a new reactor process.